# How to force subclasses to have constant reference to an enum?

Tags: java, enums

I have an abstract class, and I want to force its subclasses to reference an Enum member. Here's a simplified version of what I have:

```
public abstract class Action {

    public static enum ImpactType {
        Size(2), Position(2), Scale(1)

        final int elements;
        private ImpactType (int elements){
            this.elements = elements;
        }
    }

    protected abstract ImpactType impactType();
    protected abstract apply(float value, int element);

    public void apply(float value) {
        for (int i=0; i<impactType.elements; i++)
            apply(value, i);
    }
}
```

and an example implementation:

```
public class PositionAction extends Action {

    Vector2 target;

    public PositionAction(Vector2 target){
        this.target= target;
    }

    protected ImpactType impactType(){ return ImpactType.Position; };

    protected abstract apply(float value, int element){
        switch (element){
        case 0:
            target.x = value;
            break;
        case 1:
            target.y = value;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that this doesn't enforce the `impactType` method returning the same thing every time. In fact, two different instances of the subclass could potentially return different `ImpactType`s, but I need to be sure that each subclass is locked to a single member of the enum because of other operations I'm doing on these objects. Any ideas of how to solve this?

Comment: Sometimes you have to trust other coders to follow specifications.

Comment: instead of creating a method `impactType()`, why dont you specify a private `ImpactType` field in your concrete classes?

Comment: Aren't you controlling these implementations?

Comment: You could mark the method final.  Final methods can't be overridden.

Comment: Can you expand on the use case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enforce the restriction by requiring the subclass to provide an ImpactType on construction.

```
public abstract class Action {
    private final ImpactType m_impactType;

    Action( ImpactType impactType ) {
         m_impactType = impactType;
    }

    protected final ImpactType impactType() { 
        return m_impactType; 
    }
    ...
 }
```

Then your subclasses can provide their impact type via `super()`:

```
public class PositionAction extends Action {
    private Vector2 target;

    public PositionAction(Vector2 target){
        super( ImpactType.Position );
        this.target= target;
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Final methods can't be overridden.  This allows you to lock an implementation so it can't be changed by subclasses.

```
protected final ImpactType impactType(){ return ImpactType.Position; };
```

Alternatively, you can do as @javaguest suggested and simply make the ImpactType a private final field with a public getter.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but both of these solutions only work if I'm the only one creating subclasses.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something.  Why not just create the PositionAction, SizeAction, and ScaleAction abstract classes yourself?  Don't even expose the base abstract class.

Comment: Didn't think of that. That would solve all the issues.